# Having difficulties setting if statements in CSS() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is to set a border-top-left-radius(80px) to a rectangular shaped box when a button is clicked, then after 2 seconds I want the border-bottom-right-radius to be 100px. Now till this, everything works just fine.
But when I tried to set the border-radius to back to 0px, it didn't work. 
Why didn't it work? Please solve my problem!

~Sorry for my bad English, Thank you so much~
Here's the HTML of my code:

```
<div class="box"> A Box! </div>
<button class="css"> Slice The Box! </button>
```

The CSS for the box:

```
 .box{
    background: #d05200;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  button{
    border: 1px solid #ff6800;
    background: #db7732;
    color: #fff;
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(".css").click(function(){
    if($(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius") == "0px"){
      $(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius", "80px");
    }
    if($(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius") == "80px"){
      setTimeout( function(){
          $('.box').css('borderBottomRightRadius','100px');
        }, 2000);
      }

     if($(".box").css("borderBottomRightRadius") == "100px"){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.box').css('borderRadius', '0px');
      }, 1000);
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the flow to go 0 to 80, wait 2 seconds, 80 to 100, wait a second, and then go back to 0?  If so that is not what setTimeout does.  setTimeout creates a parallel process which will run after the time provided passes.  It does not pause your logic.  If you want things to run in sequence you will have to nest your logic within the respected setTimeouts so they run when they should.

Comment: Seems to work just as expected -> https://jsfiddle.net/fr5tjtbw/ Note that the second time you click, the value is `80px` and both the first and last timeout runs

Comment: Here's how to solve it -> https://jsfiddle.net/fr5tjtbw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is if you want it to do all three in sequence.

```js
$(".css").click(function(){
    if($(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius") == "0px"){
      $(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius", "80px");

      setTimeout( function(){
          $('.box').css('borderBottomRightRadius','100px');

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.box').css('borderRadius', '0px');
          }, 1000);
      }, 2000);
    }
});
```

```css
 .box{
    background: #d05200;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  button{
    border: 1px solid #ff6800;
    background: #db7732;
    color: #fff;
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"> A Box! </div>
<button class="css"> Slice The Box! </button>
```

Comment: If this is indeed what you are after, I would instead suggest you take a look at making this a css transition and just add/remove the associated class to do the transitions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion! **Thumbs Up**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".css").click(function(){
if($(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius") == "0px"){
  $(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius", "80px");
}
     if($(".box").css("borderTopLeftRadius") == "80px"){
           setTimeout( function(){
      $('.box').css('borderBottomRightRadius','100px');

             if($(".box").css("borderBottomRightRadius") == "100px"){
                   setTimeout(function(){
    $('.box').css('borderRadius', '0px');
  }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
  }
 });
```